# Eliminar uso innecesario de memoria en Array con C

Tags: array, c

Tengo creado un programa el cual te pide que introduzcas números y que acaba cuando introduces -1.

Me gustaría saber como usar solo el espacio necesario para el array, es decir, en un principio el array creado es int numero[N] donde N = 100, la cosa es que si por ejemplo el usuario introduce:  1 2 3 4 5 -1 habría mucho espacio hasta numero[100], he oído hablar de malloc pero no sé si es la mejor opción y tampoco la he usado nunca.

¿Qué me recomendáis?

Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

int main(){
    int numero[N];
    int i;
    printf("Introduzca los numeros: ");
    for(i=0; numero[i-1]!=-1 && i<N; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &numero[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        printf(" %d", numero[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: En lugar de declararlo en forma estática, pides memoria con `malloc` y cuando terminas de ingresar, aplicas `realloc` para devolver la porción que no ocupaste.

Comment: Entonces hago esto: ```int *numero;
numero=(int *)malloc(sizeof(float) * 100);``` Pero no sé donde debo meter realloc

Comment: @Pau deberia ser sizeof(int), si no estas mezclando tipos

Comment: Cierto me equivoque al escribirlo aquí. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Vas por buen camino, tu trabajo es investigar y estudiar malloc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Con malloc

Lo que tendias que hacer es mas o menos lo siguiente:

1. Asignar la memoria:

```c
int *datos = malloc(sizeof(int)*CANTIDAD);
if (!datos) {
    printf("No se ha podido asignar la memoria");
}
```

2. Lo vas llenando, y cuando te acerques a el limite peudes asignarle mas memoria, o si terminaste puedes devolver memoria que no uses:

```c
int nuevos_datos = realloc(datos, NUEVA_CANTIDAD);
if (!nuevos_datos) {
    printf("No se ha podido agrandar el array");
    // Puedes seguir usando datos en este caso
} else {
    datos = nuevos_datos;
}
```

3. Al final liberas la memoria

```
free(datos);
```

No te guies solo con lo que viste aqui, invesitga como usar estas funciones. Veras que le vas a sumar complejidad a tu problema.

#### Mi recomendación

Bueno, la verdad es que creo que el añadir la complejidad de trabajar con memoria dinamicamente no vale la pena por 380 bytes.

Comment: Muchas graciass!!